# Bounce balls inside ellipsoid and other shapes vpython

Tags: python, vpython

How?
I'm sure this should be simple...have tried this
Would love a push in right direction (newbie)

```
lips = ellipsoid(pos=vector(0,0,0),opacity=.4)
lips.axis=vector(2,0,0)


ball = sphere (color = color.green, radius = 0.1, make_trail=True, retain=200)
ball.mass = 1.0
ball.p = vector (-0.15, -0.23, +0.27)

dt = 0.3
while True:
    rate(200)
    ball.pos = ball.pos + (ball.p/ball.mass)*dt
    if not (lips > ball.pos.x > -lips):
        ball.p.x = -ball.p.x
    if not (lips > ball.pos.y > -lips):
        ball.p.y = -ball.p.y
    if not (lips > ball.pos.z > -lips):
        ball.p.z = -ball.p.z
```

Comment: I think a good approximation would be to find the tangent of the curve  representing the shape at the point of impact and "bounce" the ball off that. The math could get involved depending on the formula for curved shape (like an ellipse). An approximation of _that_ might be just take two close-together points that lie on the curve and consider that the tangent.

Comment: yes, that's beyond me right now, though definitely part of the programme...I was hoping that the vectors for the 'ellipsoid' were discoverable/imbedded and therefore one could just refer to the shape as vector space to bounce off...failing that possibility means as you suggest code to calculate tangent line at each point of contact to calculate the angle of incidence and reflection..I don't mind discovering this the scenic way... How would you code for an ellipsoid in order to have usable curved vector space/shape for this purpose?.., thank you for your interest.

Comment: On idea that might work would to compute the tangent based on the perpendicular formed from the center of the ellipsoid to the point of contact by the ball.

Comment: It occurs to me that you might be able to use VPython's vector machinery like this: Consider a vector v of magnitude R that goes from the center to some point on a sphere and assume the ellipsoid has its long axis along the x axis, and that the half-length of the ellipsoid is d. I think if you multiply v.x by d/R it will point to a corresponding point on the ellipsoid. You could display a small sphere at the end of v to see this. Similarly you may need to scale v.y and v.z.

Comment: I'll comment that for VPython questions it's better to post to the VPython forum, where there are many more VPython users who will see your question than if you post to stackoverflow:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups&hl=en#!forum/vpython-users

Comment: @user1114907 Not quite sure how to obtain R... Today I have spent all day on this ! :)... Am now attempting to use the sum distance of ball from foci points (example in next comment) but getting to many syntactical errors in the construction of argument.I will also try plotting tangent Iines next. These approaches are unlinked to the actual "ellipsoid" shape though and not certain yet if a self made construction of ellipsoid is possible and will 'show' in Vpython. I am still surprised that the geometry is not discoverable...? can't see anything in documentation ...but having fun with challenge

Comment: ball = sphere(pos=vec(0,0,0), color=color.orange, radius=.02, make_trail=True)
ball.p = vec(.5,.6,.8)
dt=0.3
bp=ball.pos
F1 = vec(1,0,0)
F2 = vec(-1,0,0)
C = (F1+bp)+(F2+bp)
print (C)

while True:
    rate(25)
    ball.pos = ball.pos + ball.p*dt
    
    if (ball.pos.x >= C):
            ball.p.x = -ball.p.x
    if (ball.pos.y >= C):
            ball.p.y = -ball.p.y
    if (ball.pos.z >= C):
            ball.p.z = -ball.p.z

Comment: I answered in the VPython forum.